# Switching to biblatex: how to load custom elsarticle-harv.bst style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

As I am switching to `biblatex` for some specific purpose, but the default citation style could not fulfill the need.

By `natbib`:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} % author-year
```

is used to load special style.

By `biblatex`:

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

seems not working.

Since I had no clue to find the relevant command to load [this `.bst` file](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst) in the extremely long package manual, so how to figure this out?

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your questions: [What to do to switch to biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/2693)?

Comment: There is no information about how to load specific `.bst` file :(

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Maybe the question's objective should be rephrased to: "How do I mimic the layout achieved by `elsarticle-harv` if I use `biblatex` instead of `BibTeX`"?

Comment: @KOF -- Could you please be a bit more specific about the "specific purpose" that's leading you from using `natbib`/`elsarticle-harv`/`BibTeX` to an alternative solution based on bibLaTeX?

Comment: I wanna put references after each chapters instead of at the end of document. The solutions I found will need biblatex package. Besides, there are so many posts discussing `biblatex`, so maybe i could make use of the advantage of it.

Comment: @KOF Your comment about the information not being there is interesting, since it is there, but perhaps not phrased in a way that allowed you to make the right connections. This is more a comment on the answers there than on your understanding of them. The equivalent of a `.bst` file is a style specified in the `\usepackage[style=<a-biblatex-style>]{biblatex}` command. There is no one-to-one correspondence between existing `natbib` styles and `biblatex` styles, but there are a lot of harvard like styles for `biblatex`.  A lot depends on how exactly you need to use the `elsarticle-harv` style.

Comment: @AlanMunn  `style=elsarticle-harv` option does not work. Could you please give the link of those style files for `biblatex`?

Comment: Here's a link to the [`biblatex-contrib`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib) folder of CTAN.  All of these styles should be part of TeXLive and MikTeX, so you shouldn't need to download them separately if your distribution is complete and up-to-date.  If you don't have them, you should use regular methods for adding packages to your distribution (`tlmgr` for TeXLive or its MikTeX equivalent.)

Comment: @AlanMunn - From my experience with the bibliography style `elsarticle-harv`, the only clear "Harvard-like" attribute is its implementation of an *author-year* citation system -- something first achieved on a stable basis, if memory serves me correctly, by the `harvard` package, quite some time before the `natbib` package came around. For journals published by Elsevier, the recommendation is always to use the `natbib` package. The "harv" in `elsarticle-harv` may thus be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Audrey so succinctly notes in the comments, (and as Mico and I commented on your question) you simply can't use `.bst` files with `biblatex`. So the best solution would be to find existing `biblatex` style that comes close to the `elsarticle-harv` style.

Since the `elsarticle-harv` is a generic author-year style, the first place to start might be one of the standard `author-year` styles that `biblatex` provides.  If they are not sufficient, perhaps you could try the `apa` style for biblatex.  This produces fairly standard Author-Year citations and bibliography.  Here's a simple example with references per chapter added to the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{book}
% The next 4 lines are required for the biblatex-apa style
% adding the refsection=chapter option makes allows each chapter to have a 
% references section
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,refsection=chapter]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
% load your bib file (.bib suffix required)
\addbibresource{newmainjournals.bib}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
% insert some citation commands in your text
% at the end of the chapter, print the bibliography as a section, added to TOC
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
% now repeat for the next chapter 
\chapter{Second Chapter}
% some more citation commands
% and the next references section
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: The short answer should probably be: You can't use BST style files with biblatex.