# How to use custom bibstyle with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using Biblatex for bibliography. This works fine with builtin styles like ieee. But when I gave a custom bst file I got it gives me not found error.

My command was

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=splncs]{biblatex}
```

I put the file splncs.bst in the same folder containing the tex and bib file.

Biblatex works fine when inbuilt styles are used

Comment: You cannot use `.bst` files with `biblatex`. `biblatex` styles are `.bbx` and `.cbx` files.

Comment: Can convert between these two? What should be done if i get a bst file?

Comment: There is no standard conversion way from `.bst` to `.bbx`/`.cbx`. If you *have* to use a `.bst` file, better use BibTeX. If there is just a general style you have to follow, you might be able to cook that style up with `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe -- Until the unlikely event that someone actually creates a bst-->bbx/cbx converter, your comments are the answer....  To the OP: while it is a lot of work to create a fully correct and complete bibliography/citation style, if your needs are personal and (somewhat) circumscribed, it is possible to implement a style for use with `biblatex` without too much work.  There are many serious `biblatex` hackers who frequent this site if you have questions.

Comment: See also [Switching to biblatex: how to load custom elsarticle-harv.bst style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96958/35864) and [Biblatex induced headache: Bibliography bst style not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864).

Answer (score 15):

`biblatex` uses a different style format (`.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.lbx`) than BibTeX (`.bst`). That means **you cannot use** your **`.bst` files** (BibTeX styles/`\bibliographystyle`s) **together with `biblatex`** (or Biber, for that matter).

Note also that you can't use your `.bst` files with Biber. While Biber is a replacement for BibTeX when used for `biblatex`, it can not deal with `.bst` files at all and so would be of no use as a replacement for BibTeX in the classic BibTeX bibliography set-up.

---

As far as I'm aware there is no "converter" for `.bst` to `.bbx`/`.cbx`, and it is very unlikely that someone will actually create such a converter. Joseph suggests in the comment that this is impossible.

As a general rule: If you *have* to use a certain `.bst` file (because you institution requires you to do so, your publisher insists on a certain template etc.) it is best to go with BibTeX and the exact setup recommended in the guidelines.
If you just happen to like a particular `.bst` file, you can check first if someone has created a `biblatex` style for it (a list of styles can be found [here](http://www.ctan.org/topic/biblatex)), if that is not the case, you can try and create the style yourself.

To implement a bibliography style yourself, first choose an appropriate basis for your style, find the standard `biblatex` style that comes closest to your intended style (as a rule of thumb the standard styles are easier to modify than heavily customised styles like `biblatex-chicago`, `biblatex-apa`, these only lends themselves to be used as a basis if the changes needed are miniscule).
According to [this](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/splncs.pdf), that would probably `numeric` in your case.

Then you go on to modify the style to your needs. A started is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), but there are much more questions about all kinds of customisations on this site.

Comment: I'd go further than 'very unlikely' on auto-conversion: once you give this some thought it's impossible. Such a conversion would need some form of structure to be available in the input, and `.bst` files are entirely arbitrary.