# How to import an external bibliography style file if using 'usepackage{biblatex}' and PdfLatex compiler instead of BibTex compiler

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sharelatex

recently, I've moved my latex editor from the desktop version 'TexMaker' to the online version 'ShareLatex'. Then I've got a bibliography issue - that is, the 'Reference' section is totally missing at the end of the paper, as well as the missing citation. In my paper draft, I was simple using `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` to import the style and print the 'Reference' section. Through the desktop 'TexMaker', I can compile it via 'BibTex' once; then compile it again via 'PDFLaTex'. Yet, 'ShareLatex' does not have 'BibTex' compiler. According to their documentation, it is recommended to use `\usepackage{biblatex}`, `\addbibresource`, and `\printbibliography`. But I cannot find a way to import an external bibliography style file. Has anyone encountered a similar issue ?

Comment: Can you post complete example code that shows your problem?

Comment: Sharelatex supports both bibliographies using traditional bibtex style and biblatex style.

Comment: If by "bibliography style file" you refer to `.bst` files, you cannot use those together with `biblatex` (neither on ShareLaTeX nor anywhere else). But you don't have to use `biblatex` on ShareLaTeX, you can still use standard BibTeX methods, they only recommend `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, by 'the external bibliography style file', I mean a '*.bst' file. Could you tell me more specific about 'you can still use standard BibTeX methods on ShareLatex' ? On my source, I simple use '\bibliographystyle' and '\bibliography'. Through the desktop editor - 'TexMaker', I can compile it via 'BibTex' first; then 'PDFLatex' to generate the 'Reference' and correct citation. But on ShareLatex, there is no 'BibTex' complier option. I can only compile it through 'PDFLatex', which cause no 'Reference' and missing citation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

The root cause has been identified with the help from ShareLatex support. ShareLatex does support BibTex; yet it seems not to handle the relative path very well. The file location of my '.tex' is not the same as that of '.bib' and '*.bst'. So, to put them under the same path / folder, the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two issues here.

Firstly, `biblatex` cannot deal with `.bst` files; it uses its own system of `.bbx`, `.cbx` and `.lbx` files for style definitions.
If you want to use `.bst` files you will have to resort to classical BibTeX.
See for example [Switching to biblatex: how to load custom elsarticle-harv.bst style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96958/35864), [How to use custom bibstyle with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174676/35864) and [Biblatex induced headache: Bibliography bst style not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864).

---

Secondly, you seem to think that ShareLaTeX does not support BibTeX. As [Bibliography management with bibtex](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex) and especially [the example](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/new/template?zipUrl=/project/535ec803337a0f8a1a87952e/download/zip&templateName=bibtex-example&compiler=pdflatex) on that page demonstrate that fear is idle. ShareLaTeX can very well deal with BibTeX and automatically runs it once you press the *recompile* button.

In the screenshot below you can see BibTeX project happily working in ShareLaTeX (it is an adapted version of the example linked to above)

[image: screen shot of a BibTeX project in ShareLaTeX]

The page merely recommends using `biblatex` because of its flexibility and localisation facilities.
Indeed ShareLaTeX is also fully compatible with `biblatex` with both the Biber and BibTeX backend and automatically decides which to run.

Comment: Thanks. The root cause has been identified with the help from ShareLatex support. ShareLatex does support BibTex; yet it seems not to handle the relative path very well. The file location of my '*.tex' is not the same as that of '*.bib' and '*.bst'. So, to put them under the same path / folder, the problem can be solved.